# DataTable.Select with AND conditions doesn't give expected results

Tags: vb.net, select, datatable

I'm trying to compare two datatables and I'm doing some tests using `DataTable.Select` on two identical datatables:

```
Using DT_NewData As DataTable = DT_DBData.Copy
    For x As Short = 0 To DT_NewData.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim SelRows As DataRow() = DT_DBData.Select( _
            "Type='" & DT_NewData.Rows(x)("Type") & "'" & _
            " AND In_Date='" & DT_NewData.Rows(x)("In_Date") & "'" & _
            " AND Out_Date='" & DT_NewData.Rows(x)("Out_Date") & "'")
    Next
```

But `SelRows.Length` is always 0. What's wrong in my code?

Comment: You should use `Option Strict On` then it wouldn't compile. You cannot concat objects with `&` just strings. I assume that `In_Date` and `Out_Date` are date-columns. With Option Strict Off they are converted to string automatically by using `ToString`. That doesn't return the invariant culture format of date which is needed for `DataTable.Select` but the format of your current culture. So use `DT_NewData.Rows(x).Field(Of Date)("In_Date").ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ok. I understood my error. Anyway your suggestion returns `Invalid Cast Exception` when a field is `DBNull`. Can you suggest another way?

Answer (score 0):

Although is a little strange the copy of the table, try this:

Suppose that `Type` is `String`

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Linq

Module StartupModule

Sub Main()
    ' Declare the table.
    Dim originalDataTable As New DataTable

    ' Declare the table columns.
    With originalDataTable.Columns
        .Add("Type", GetType(String))
        .Add("InDate", GetType(DateTime))
        .Add("OutDate", GetType(DateTime))
    End With

    ' Delegate to add rows.
    Dim addRow As Action(Of String, DateTime?, DateTime?) = Sub(text, inDate, outDate)
    Dim newRow As DataRow = originalDataTable.NewRow()

    With newRow
        If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) Then
            .SetField(Of String)("Type", text)
        End If

        If (inDate.HasValue) Then
            .SetField(Of DateTime?)("InDate", inDate.Value)
        End If

        If (outDate.HasValue) Then
            .SetField(Of DateTime?)("OutDate", outDate.Value)
        End If
    End With

    originalDataTable.Rows.Add (newRow)
End Sub

' Adding rows to the table.
addRow("type1", #2/2/2017#, Nothing)
addRow(Nothing, #1/25/2016#, Nothing)
addRow(Nothing, Nothing, #1/30/2016#)

' Copy the table
Dim copiedDataTable As DataTable = originalDataTable.Copy

' Loop through copied table rows.
For i As Integer = 0 To copiedDataTable.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim type As String = copiedDataTable.Rows(i).Field(Of String)("Type")
    Dim inDate As DateTime? = copiedDataTable.Rows(i).Field(Of DateTime?)("InDate")
    Dim outDate As DateTime? = copiedDataTable.Rows(i).Field(Of DateTime?)("OutDate")

    ' Using DataTable Select.
    Dim filter As String = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}",
        If(type Is Nothing, "( Type Is Null )", String.Format("( Type = '{0}' )", type)),
        If(Not inDate.HasValue, "And ( InDate Is Null )", String.Format("And ( InDate = '{0}' )", inDate.Value.ToString())),
        If(Not outDate.HasValue, "And ( OutDate Is Null )", String.Format("And ( OutDate = '{0}' )", outDate.Value.ToString())))

    Dim usingSelectRows As DataRow() = originalDataTable.Select(filter)
    Console.WriteLine("usingSelectRows.Count = {0}", usingSelectRows.Count)

    ' Using Linq.
    Dim typeSelector As Func(Of DataRow, Boolean) = Function(r)
    If (IsNothing(type)) Then
        Return IsNothing(r.Field(Of String)("Type"))
    Else
        Return r.Field(Of String)("Type") = type
    End If
End Function

    Dim inDateSelector As Func(Of DataRow, Boolean) = Function(r)
    If (Not inDate.HasValue) Then
        Return Not r.Field(Of DateTime?)("InDate").HasValue
    Else
        Return r.Field(Of DateTime?)("InDate").GetValueOrDefault.CompareTo(inDate.GetValueOrDefault) = 0
    End If
End Function

    Dim outDateSelector As Func(Of DataRow, Boolean) = Function(r)
    If (Not outDate.HasValue) Then
        Return Not r.Field(Of DateTime?)("OutDate").HasValue
    Else
        Return r.Field(Of DateTime?)("OutDate").GetValueOrDefault.CompareTo(outDate.GetValueOrDefault) = 0
    End If
End Function

    Dim usingLinqRows = From r In originalDataTable.AsEnumerable
                Where
                    (typeSelector(r)) AndAlso
                    (inDateSelector(r)) AndAlso
                    (outDateSelector(r))
                Select r

    Console.WriteLine("usingLinqRows.Count = {0}", usingLinqRows.Count)

    Console.WriteLine()
Next

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

End Module
```

Always use the [Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension of `DataRow` to retrieve data.

Comment: Have you tested it? Also with `DBNull` data fields? On my scenario `SelRows.Length` is 0.

Comment: @genespos I have edited my answer with a full example.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but I'm not a pro and I'm trying to solve by comparing each cell (after sorting)

Comment: No problem my friend. The problem starts with Null values in data table. Hope my example helped.